# data.gov: Request for insight into relationships of Topics / Categories / Organizations etc

Tags: data.gov, categories

I have just started exploring data.gov and want to ensure i understand relationships under a Topic.
If I pick a topic, then it lists # of datasets mapped to the topic. Then we have Categories, Tags, Organizations, Publishers and Bureaus. I can infer the following:

- A dataset mapped to a Topic can show in another Topic as well
- Datasets published by an Organization add up to the total data set for the topic

- What is the purpose of Categories under a Topic? A subclassing below Topic?
- Is Organization, Publisher and Bureau any linkage that can be inferred?
- Is there a metrics download where I can get stats on the above constructs? I did download a metrics file but it has stats on agency/ subagency and datasets. Eg: Topic of Finance = 102 datasets. Is this metric and others like these downloadable?